# Use one or another interface type in Typescript/React

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Having this type:

```
export interface IMyTypes {
  First: {
    name: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    status: string;
  };
  Second: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;
  };
}
```

This must be used in a component but I cannot make it accept both, the props should be First or Second.

I can make it work for First:

```
import { IMyTypes } from '../my-types';

interface MyComponentProps {
  componentProps: ComponentProps<IMyTypes['First']>;
}
```

or for the second:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  componentProps: ComponentProps<IMyTypes['Second']>;
}
```

But doesn't work to make it accept one or the other, tried like the following but it isn't correct:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  componentProps: ComponentProps<IMyTypes['First' | 'Second']>;
}
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `ComponentProps<IMyTypes['First'] | IMyTypes['Second']>`. Wrapping `First` and `Second` in `interface` looks strange...

Comment: Or `ComponentProps<IMyTypes[keyof IMyTypes]>`

Comment: Most of all you will reuse 'First' and 'Second' later, so simply extract them as separate type or interface and use in componentProps. In case of further error - please add it to the post

Comment: @AlekseyL. I've got the following error: Type 'ComponentProps<{ name: string; city: string; country: string; status: string}, any>' is not assignable to type  'ComponentProps<{ name: string; city: string; country: string; status: string; } | { ...; }, any >'

Comment: Check out Union Types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that solves the issue:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  componentProps:
    | ComponentProps<IMyTypes['First']>
    | ComponentProps<IMyTypes['Second']>;
}
```